# URL status check is failing with if, elif

Tags: python

I cannot check the status for 2nd and 3rd URL and fail's to go to 4th url.

I have tried to used condition's but failing with- requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:, & requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:

Here is the code-

```
import requests

for url in ['google.com', 'cchgroup.com', 'skypeassets.com', 'yahoo.com']:

    http = ("http://")
    url2 = (http + url)
    page = requests.get(url2)
        #page.max_redirects = 60
    if page.status_code == 200:
        print('Success')
    elif page.status_code == 404:
        print('Not Found')
    elif requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print('Exceeded 30 redirects')
    elif requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print('Failed to establish a new connection')
    else:
        print('URL cannot be found')
```

but getting error's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'cchgroup' and 'skypeassets.com' throw exceptions. You should be using try / except block for handling them. 
This should work for you

```
import requests

for url in ['google.com', 'cchgroup.com', 'skypeassets.com', 'yahoo.com']:

    http = ("http://")
    url2 = (http + url)
    #page.max_redirects = 60
    try:
        page = requests.get(url2)
        if page.status_code == 200:
            print('Success')
        elif page.status_code == 404:
           print('Not Found')
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print('Exceeded 30 redirects')
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print('Failed to establish a new connection')
```